# FragmentActivity closes when back button pressed from its fragment

Tags: android-fragmentactivity, fragment-backstack

I have fragment activity from which I call say *Fragment A* then *Fragment B* from *Fragment A* and so on. I used backstack properties. So when I click back button from fragment B I goes to fragment A. But from fragment A it does not going to fragment Activity instead it exit from the activity and going to main activity.
Any help

My Fragment Activity

```
public class ShowAllAccounts extends FragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_all_accounts);
       ......

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    TableViewFragment mTableViewFragment = new TableViewFragment();                      
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.table_fragment_container, mTableViewFragment,"tabFrag");

                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
             }


}
```

In my Table view fragment

```
 ViewAccountDetailsFragment AccountViewFragment = new ViewAccountDetailsFragment();
                                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.table_fragment_container, AccountViewFragment, "viewAcctFrag");
                                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                                AccountViewFragment.setArguments(dataBundle);
                                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

from here i am calling account view fragment

i am having one more doubt here. From second fragment(only view) i am calling another  activity(for edit) and if i want to cancel edit of this activity can i able to go to previous fragment ie. second fragment which was meant to view details.????

please help i am new in android

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: see updated with code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your stack is empty do you use Intent Flags?
Try a look here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

if ya have just one Activity 
override the OnBackPress event and do your thing just return or something.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   return;
}
```

Xamarin People:

```
    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        base.OnBackPressed();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: did ya read http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Yes than its normal that android closes you activity and Finish it just override the OnBackPress event and do your thing there.

Comment: so what to do? i have to add flag and then??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104164/discussion-between-stefan-van-de-laarschot-and-androidbeginner).